# Having an issue with <iframe>

Tags: html, iframe, web, display

For some reasons, after trying every possible solution including rewriting my whole HTML file, rewriting the  part, changing the name of the file I want to show at least three times, tried putting directly the http:// as src, nothing is working!

It just show a page of my hoster saying that something went wrong and the page seems to be missing or misconfigurated, but it's not missing as I even wrote stuff into it, and both the name of the file and the one in the HTML one corresponds. It's not either misconfigurated, since my PHP file can write stuff into the txt file, but it's just somehow the HTML file that doesn't display it.

```
<iframe src="register.txt" width="640px" height="240px" frameborder="0" style="background-color:white">
```

EDIT: It worked after changing the extension to .lst

Comment: you are linking to register.txt, you have to link to an html page in an iframe

Comment: it's not working either it's txt or html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `</iframe>` closing tag is missing.

Comment: it's not from that, it was working without it. tried putting it, but no difference in the result.

Comment: What is the url of your page, so I might have a look at it.

Comment: File is not locked by writing to it? Might be something with permissions? Just some wild guesses.

Answer (score 0):

this is iframe code, change register.txt to the page you want in the iframe
    `<iframe src="register.txt" width="640px" height="240px" frameborder="0" style="background-color:white">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>`